# How do I export x,y,z coordinates from meshgrid arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to generate x,y,z coordinates in order to create an idealised landscape for use in GIS software and modelling. I am new to python and it will definitely show.

To do this, I would like to create a grid of x,y,z points at regular grid intervals. x represents latitude, y, longitude and z, elevation.

I can break the landscape into several sections, which can then be stitched together:

1. rectangles of constant elevation (z=constant)
2. rectangles where z is dependent on either x, or y. For example a slope, where z increases with increasing x.

I've got as far as using meshgrid, which has created a series of arrays. I just need to extract each corresponding array position together in order export x,y,z data.

I will eventually do this with a much larger dataset but the code below is for 16 points.

## test run

`import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

## create coordinates spaced by 30 and starting at x=313000, y=6220000, z is constant at 15

```
sp=(30)
x=np.arange(313000, 313120, sp)
y=np.arange(6220000,6220120, sp)
z=np.repeat(15,4)
x_mesh, y_mesh, z_mesh=np.meshgrid(x,y,z)
```

## show scatter plot of grid

```
plt.scatter(x_mesh, y_mesh, z_mesh)
plt.show
```

## create coordinates from the meshgrid

`coords=???
print(coords)`

## export the coords to csv file

`import csv`

`with open('coords.csv','w') as f:
    out = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    out.writerows(zip(*coords))
    f.close()`

Comment: I tried to also make a section of elevation when z is dependent on x but the 'coords=[]' section returned an error:TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration.  I ended up posting a second question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537035/how-do-i-create-x-y-z-coordinates-from-three-arrays-where-x-and-y-are-generated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
coords = []
for a, b, c in  zip(x_mesh, y_mesh, z_mesh):
    for a1, b1, c1 in zip(a, b, c):
        for a2, b2, c2 in zip(a1, b1, c1):
            coords.append((a2, b2, c2,))
```

Or 
List comprehension

```
coords = [(a2, b2, c2,) for a, b, c in zip(x_mesh, y_mesh, z_mesh) for a1, b1, c1 in zip(a, b, c) for a2, b2, c2 in zip(a1, b1, c1)]
```

The length of `coords` depends on the number here `z=np.repeat(15, x)`, it has a relation of 
`Number of points * x`
Your plot, will plot 16 points with x = 1 too.
As you increase x, every point gets duplicated x times.

Comment: Thank you so much Rahul! It worked! I just had to remove the zip from out.writerows and it's working perfectly.

Comment: @KayaWilson It would be appreciated if you accept the answer that help you, for other users in future to reference.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't know that is how it workd. Answer accepted!