# How do I create x,y,z coordinates from three arrays, where x and y are generated with meshgrid and z is dependent on x?

Tags: python

I am trying to create x,y,z coordinates to generate an elevation dataset. 
I was able to create x,y,z arrays with meshgrid- where z is a constant value.

(This is a follow on from my previous question and I am new to python)

I also want to create sloping terrain, where z is dependent on x.

I was able to create an array with the correct z values. However when trying to combine the three arrays (x,y,z) into coordinates using the zip tool, I got this error:

```
    TypeError   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-6454cf2caa60> in <module>
      3 for a, b, c in  zip(x_mesh, y_mesh, z_int):
     4     for a1, b1, c1 in zip(a, b, c):
----> 5         for a2, b2, c2 in zip(a1, b1, c1):
      6             coords.append((a2, b2, c2,))

TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

The code below is for a small area as a test for creating a slope over a much larger area.

I thought it may have been initially because my z array was in float and not int, so I converted it, but it made no difference.

My code with z as a constant incorporated z into meshgrid and the coords[] code worked well in that instance.

```
sp=(10)
x=np.arange(313000, 333000, sp)
y=np.arange(6220000,6227000, sp)
z=15

x_mesh, y_mesh, z_mesh=np.meshgrid(x,y,z)


coords = []
for a, b, c in  zip(x_mesh, y_mesh, z_mesh):
    for a1, b1, c1 in zip(a, b, c):
        for a2, b2, c2 in zip(a1, b1, c1):
            coords.append((a2, b2, c2,))
```

However when I tried to make z dependent on x and not include it in the meshgrid process, the 'coords=[]' part returned the error: 
    TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration

```
import numpy as np
sp=10
svx=313000
evx=313040
x=np.arange(svx,evx,sp)
y=np.arange(6220000,6220040,sp)

x_mesh, y_mesh =np.meshgrid(x,y)

evz=-30
totalnosteps=((evx-svx)/sp)-1

nosteps=((x_mesh-svx)/sp)

dedep=(evz/totalnosteps)

z=nosteps*dedep

z_int=z.astype(int)

coords = []
for a, b, c in  zip(x_mesh, y_mesh, z_int):
    for a1, b1, c1 in zip(a, b, c):
        for a2, b2, c2 in zip(a1, b1, c1):
            coords.append((a2, b2, c2,))
```

I'm after an end result with (x,y,z)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the

```
for a2, b2, c2 in zip(a1, b1, c1):
```

part, and rewrite the coords.append to

```
coords.append(a1, b1, c1)
```

The error about "needs to be iterable" is because when you iterate over zip(a, b, c), you're getting a tuple of integer, and not a tuple of np.array.

Answer (score 0):

You have different shape in those two code versions. You can use code below to get information:

```py
print(x_mesh.shape)
print(y_mesh.shape)
print(z_mesh.shape)

# code version one's output
(700, 2000, 1)
(700, 2000, 1)
(700, 2000, 1)

# code version two's output
(4, 4)
(4, 4)
(4, 4)
```

In order to solve this problem, you can use code below to add one dimension

```py
x_mesh = x_mesh[..., None]
y_mesh = y_mesh[..., None]
z = z[..., None]
```