# Generate x,y,z coordinates with meshgrid and save to .csv

Tags: python, numpy, grid

I'm trying to create an evenly spaced 3D pointcloud/grid and export it to csv.

I managed to find a solution to this problem (see link and code bellow), but sadly there is no explanation and I'm scratching my head, trying to understand why the 3 FOR loops are for.

Source: [How do I export x,y,z coordinates from meshgrid arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56489365/how-do-i-export-x-y-z-coordinates-from-meshgrid-arrays)

```
import numpy as np
import csv

sp=(30)
x=np.arange(313000, 313120, sp)
y=np.arange(6220000,6220120, sp)
z=np.repeat(15,4)
x_mesh, y_mesh, z_mesh=np.meshgrid(x,y,z)

coords = []
for a, b, c in  zip(x_mesh, y_mesh, z_mesh):
    for a1, b1, c1 in zip(a, b, c):
        for a2, b2, c2 in zip(a1, b1, c1):
            coords.append((a2, b2, c2,))
print(coords)

with open('coords.csv','w') as f:
    out = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    out.writerows(zip(*coords))
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 for loops because you are using 3 axes.

nunpy meshgrid creates N-D coordinate arrays. For example, simple 2D array with 2 points in each direction:

```
x = ['x0', 'x1']
y = ['y0', 'y1']

x_mesh, y_mesh = np.meshgrid(x, y)

print('x')
print(x_mesh)
print('y')
print(y_mesh)
print('---')
```

Would print out:

```
x
[['x0' 'x1']
 ['x0' 'x1']]
y
[['y0' 'y0']
 ['y1' 'y1']]
---
```

So, to get the individual coordinates (like 'x0,y0') you need to join these together. As it's 2D you only need 2 for loops.

```
coords = []

for a, b in  zip(x_mesh, y_mesh):
    for a1, b1 in zip(a, b):
        coords.append((a1, b1))

print('coords')
print(coords)
print('---')
```

Would print out:

```
coords
[('x0', 'y0'), ('x1', 'y0'), ('x0', 'y1'), ('x1', 'y1')]
---
```

You have 3 dimensions, so meshgrid has an extra level of nested arrays. Hence the 3 for loops.